# Eclipse Plugin - execute when user changes window in perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would like to ask how would you automatically execute a plugin when a user switches windows in the perspective.

[image: change window]

Can this be done maybe with startup handler and `IWorkbench`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IPartListener` to listen to changes in which part is active.

You can set this up in using `IStartup` but you need to do this using something like this:

```java
public class StartUp implements IStartup
{
  @Override
  public void earlyStartup()
  {
    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
         if (window != null) {
           window.getPartService().addPartListener(your part listener);
         }
       }
     });
  }
}
```

This is using `Display.asyncExec` to delay setting up the part listener until after the startup has completed as the workbench window will not be available when `earlyStartup` runs.